# Why is Python decoding the \0xb7 character fine in an IDE, but not when executed standalone?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

The Address of the restaurant as shown here:

[image]

contains the "·" character. I extract this element (and the addresses of the other two) with WebDriver thus:

```
self.allAddresses = [(i.text + ', ' + ', '.join(city.split('+')) for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._ucf")]
```

For the attempted extraction of this element, I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I try handle it thus:

```
self.allAddresses = [(i.text).split('\0xb7')[0].encode('raw_unicode_escape') + ', ' + ', '.join(city.split('+')) for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._ucf")]
```

Here's the thing; with this splitting by `0xb7`, this works fine **in the IDE** (Geany). Yet when I run it **on the command line**, I get:

```
    self.allAddresses = [(i.text).split('\xb7')[0].encode('raw_unicode_escape') + ', ' + ', '.join(city.split('+')) for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._ucf")]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems that on when executed on the command line, the leading `0` in the charcater is not recognized, and so the decode fails. Why is this?

What's more, given that I actually only need the characters before the `"·"` (the characters following it are not part of the address), **if there is a better way of extracting just up to but not including to the dot** (and thereby perhaps avoiding the decoding issue completely), I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Have you tried regular expression?...and concerning your decoding issue, did you add at the top of your file this line: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: what line are you referring to?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور yep, it's already there by default in a browse-generated WebDriver program.

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond Nope - the code is the unchanged - what you see on the command line is the *0* being stripped ... therein lies my problem.

Comment: Try `(i.text).split('u\xb7')` (the `u` makes `\xb7` an unicode string)

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور yes I can use a regex to match up to the "·". Problem is, addresses with the "·" are the exception rather than the rule. So my match would be a convoluted match up to the "·" or to some unknown number of spaces ...